# Woocommerce Shopping Cart Icon

Tags: php, woocommerce, shopping-cart

I have a woocommerce cart icon in my main navigation. I want that icon to show a  if the cart has items in it. If not that  would be removed. I have tried the code below and it does not do what I intended it to. Ideas?

```
if($items_txt = $count_value === 1 ){
$html .= '<span class="xoo-wsc-sc-count">1</span>';}
elseif($items_txt = $count_value === 0 ){
$html .= '';}
```

Here is the full original code snippet.

```
<?php

// If this file is called directly, abort.
if ( ! defined( 'WPINC' ) ) {
    die;
}

$sy_options = get_option('xoo-wsc-sy-options');//Style options
$options    = get_option('xoo-wsc-gl-options');
$count_type = isset( $options['bk-count-type']) ? $options['bk-count-type'] : 'qty_count'; //Count Type
$cart_items_total = wc_price(WC()->cart->subtotal);

$bk_cubi    = isset( $sy_options['bk-cubi']) ? $sy_options['bk-cubi'] : ''; // Custom basket icon
if( !$bk_cubi ){
    $bk_bit = isset( $sy_options['bk-bit']) ? $sy_options['bk-bit'] : 'xoo-wsc-icon-basket1'; // Basket Icon Type
}


$html  = '<a class="xoo-wsc-sc-cont">';

if( $bk_cubi ){
    $html .= '<img src="'.$bk_cubi.'" class="xoo-wsc-sc-icon">';
}
else{
    $html .= '<span class="xoo-wsc-sc-icon '.$bk_bit.'"></span>';
}

if($count_type == 'qty_count'){
    $count_value = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
}
elseif($count_type == 'item_count'){
    $count_value = count(WC()->cart->get_cart());
}

$items_txt = $count_value === 1 ? __('item','side-cart-woocommerce') : __('items','side-cart-woocommerce');
$html .= '<span class="xoo-wsc-sc-count">'.'</span>';
//$html .= '<span class="xoo-wsc-sc-count">'.$count_value.'</span>';
//$html .= '<span class="xoo-wsc-sc-total">'.$cart_items_total.'</span>';



$html .= '</a>';

echo $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you change this if:

```
if( $bk_cubi ){
    $html .= '<img src="'.$bk_cubi.'" class="xoo-wsc-sc-icon">';
}
else{
    $html .= '<span class="xoo-wsc-sc-icon '.$bk_bit.'"></span>';
}
```

To:

```
if ($bk_cubi)
{
    $html .= '<img src="'.$bk_cubi.'" class="xoo-wsc-sc-icon">';
}
else
{
    if($count_value == 1 )
    {
        $html .= '<span class="xoo-wsc-sc-count">1</span>';
    }
}
```

You'll get what you want.

Also, a single `=` is assignment operator. `==` is for checking whether values are equal to one another.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments` hook to check real-time woocommerce cart items.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'woo_cart_icon_count' );
function woo_cart_icon_count( $fragments ) {

   $cart_count = WC()->cart->cart_contents_count;
   if($cart_count > 0) {
     // your code here
   }

}
```

For more detail, you can check the tutorial [here](https://yourblogcoach.com/how-to-add-woocommerce-cart-icon-in-menu/).